# Knockout.js - UI not updated after observable has been set / changed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm having a list, displaying photo-thumbs When clicking a thumb, a bootstrap modal is opened, displaying the clicked thumb as a fullscreen image.
This is done by updating an observable().

problem is.. UI's not updating, resulting in no data displayed, no image or text. Modal popup functionality is working properly.

**BUT..** when console.logging the observable. It displays the object as it should, and is updated.

So why does this seem fine when i'm console.logging it, and not in the UI ?

**Click event (inside foreach)**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#full-modal-photopage" data-bind="click: $parent.setSelectedPhoto">
    <img data-bind="attr:{src: BlobUrlPhotoThumb}" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" />
</a>
```

**Modal to display selected photo (bootstrap modal)**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="full-modal-photopage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: 999999999999">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel" data-bind="text: selectedPhoto.PhotoText "></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: selectedPhoto.BlobUrlPhoto }" id="full-modal-img" alt="" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Observable init & setSelectedPhoto script**

```
self.selectedPhoto = ko.observable();

    self.setSelectedPhoto = function(selPhoto) {
        self.selectedPhoto(selPhoto);
        console.log(self.selectedPhoto());
    }
```

**Screenshot of console.log**
[image]

Comment: How about making all the properties inside of `self.selectedPhoto` observables? because, it seems as if the main object is refershed, but the actually _bound_ properties are not updated as they are not observables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `selectedPhoto` is observable you have to add parenthesis before accessing observable's properties:

```
<h4 id="myModalLabel" data-bind="text: selectedPhoto().PhotoText "></h4>
...
<img data-bind="attr: { src: selectedPhoto().BlobUrlPhoto }" id="full-modal-img" alt="" />
```

**Update:**

Another way you may prefer is using `with` binding that sets binding context to given variable (either plain or observable). So add it to #full-modal-photopage:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="full-modal-photopage" data-bind="with: selectedPhoto" ...
```

and access properties without specifying `selectedPhoto`:

```
<h4 id="myModalLabel" data-bind="text: PhotoText "></h4>
...
<img data-bind="attr: { src: BlobUrlPhoto }" id="full-modal-img" alt="" />
```

Comment: BTW This can be made easier by employing the `with: selectedPhoto` binding on a container element.

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, I've been updating my answer when you have posted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Wow guys!.. i'd have to say great coop on this one :) Really, really glad for that example.. it solved everything, and gave me a good understanding of how this is wired up with observables and accessing them..

Answer (score 1):

Observables are functions. You can use them directly as event handlers in knockout, an extra `setSelectedPhoto()` method is superfluous:

```html
<a data-bind="click: $parent.selectedPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#full-modal-photopage">
    <img data-bind="attr:{ src: BlobUrlPhotoThumb}" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" />
</a>
```

Now `selectedPhoto` will be updated on click.

In your modal you can use `with: selectedPhoto` to a) rebuild the inner part when `selectedPhoto` changes and b) set a context for the properties you are referring to:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="full-modal-photopage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: 999999999999">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" data-bind="with: selectedPhoto">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" data-bind="text: PhotoText"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: BlobUrlPhoto }" id="full-modal-img" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this kind of setup it's not relevant whether `BlobUrlPhoto` or `PhotoText` are themselves observables or not. The `with` binding does the right thing.